# missing dll on running flash swf in swing through ezjcom

Tags: java, flash, swing

I am trying to use EZJCOM to run swf files from java (swing). Using the wizard interface I generated the java classes for flash10.ocx.
*** issue *** - at runtime it stops saying 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no EZJcomLib18 in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)

I searched on my disk - there is no EZJcomLib18.dll.

anyone able to run ezjcom for flash - can you please help me out - where can I get that dll?

thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about EZJCOM, but is this link relevant?

http://www.ezjcom.com/onlinedocs/java2com/PlaceDLL.html

It says that the installer for EZJCOM places the .dll in your System32 folder. If it's not on your disk...did you install EZJCOM?

Comment: thansk Cody for your reply. I did execute the ezjcom installer. yet it did not save the ezjcomlib18.dll anywhere in my local disk. to confirm I repeated this step again. I dont know what is missing/wrong..